# Throwing "Namespace '"../node_modules/xlsx/types/index"' has no exported member 'IWorkSheetCell'."" error while creating azure devops extension

Tags: excel, typescript, azure-devops, node-modules, vscode-extensions

I am getting the error Namespace '"../node_modules/xlsx/types/index"' has no exported member 'IWorkSheetCell' while creating the azure devops extension.

This error is occurring while using the 'xlsx' library of typescipt with the version 0.18.5.

The code I am using is shown below.

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

```
for (var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
        for (var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
            if (range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
            if (range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
            if (range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
            if (range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
            var cell: **XLSX.IWorkSheetCell** = { v: data[R][C], t: 's' };

            if (cell.v == null) continue;
            var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R });

            if (typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
            else if (typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
            else if (<any>cell.v instanceof Date) {
                cell.t = 'n';
                cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
            }
            else {
                cell.t = 's';
                cell.s = '1';
            }

            ws[cell_ref] = cell;
        }
    }
```

The error is occurring at var cell: **XLSX.IWorkSheetCell** = { v: data[R][C], t: 's' };

Please suggest me on how to resolve this or should I change the version of xlsx library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is not such option (**`IWorkSheetCell`**) under the xlsx npm package. That's why it cannot be found.

To modify the value of a cell in in a worksheet, you can try using the function **`XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa`** function. (See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#modifying-cell-values).)

To read the value of a cell, you can use **`XLSX.read`** or **`XLSX.readFile`** function.